# Firebase Loop through the Child of Child with a value of

Tags: python, firebase, loops

Under rosters there are a list of team IDs.  Im trying to loop through the team_id into the children which have additional attributes and find all with age of 1.

I've figured out how to access as far as the team_id but I can't figure out how to loop through every member and count how many meet the requirements.

```
roster_info_snapshot = cfm.child('rosters').child(team_id).get()
```

**This is code that I currently have working that returns number of injured players on a team.**

```
 # Number of injured players
elif data['name'] != 'John Madden' and '/injuries' in data['text'].lower():
    print('Injuries keyword found')
    msg = data['text'].lower().split()
    func_index = msg.index('/injuries')
    if(len(msg) > func_index + 1):
        try:
            print(f'Retrieving injuries info for {msg[func_index + 1]}')
            team_map_snapshot = cfm.child('teamMap').get()
            team_id = team_map_snapshot[msg[func_index + 1].lower()]
            team_info_snapshot = cfm.child('teams').child(team_id).get()

            msg = f"{data['name']}, you sent '{data['text']}'"
            send_message(f"{team_info_snapshot['displayName']} have {team_info_snapshot['ovrRating']} players injured")

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            send_message('Sorry, an error occurred processing your request.')

    else:
        send_message("Sorry, I couldn't find a team name associated with your request."
                    " Use '/help' to get a list of commands.")

return 'ok', 200
```

[image]

Comment: `db.child("rosters").order_by_child("age").equal_to(1).get().val()`

Comment: This help me with the syntax but perhaps my original question isn't clear.  I have it set up now where a specific team name gets searched by user.  The name is associated with a teamID (ex.778043392).  Within the team are individual members which are identified by (0,1,10,11,12 etc).   Im trying to go into rosters, find the matching ID, and search throuch all members (0,1,10,11,12 etc.) that equal 1.   Hope this is clearer  I appreciate the help.

Comment: `team_info_snapshot = cfm.child('rosters').child(team_id).get()
                    print(team_info_snapshot)`   this code prints all of the attributes and its values of the selected teamId.

Comment: *"all of the attributes and its values of the selected teamId"*: Then loop these result. Like `for team in team_info_snapshot:` there sould be a `team['age']` item.

Comment: yes you are correct but I think my syntax may be off because I'm now generating and error when I run  `for team in team_info_snapshot.items() if team['age'] == 1
print(team)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Loop through the Child of Child
>   **Comment**:  `team_info_snapshot = cfm.child('teams').child(team_id).get()` generates multiple instances of
>   `[{'accelRating': 96, 'age': 27, 'agilityRating': 91, 'awareRating': 87, 'bCVRating'....etc}]`

The result are `list` of `dict`.

```
team_info_snapshot = cfm.child('teams').child(team_id).get()
count = 0
for team in team_info_snapshot:
    print(team) # {'accelRating': 96, 'age': 27, 'agilityRating': 91, ...etc}
    print(team['age']) # 27

    if team['age'] == 27:
        count += 1
```

---

- [Pyrebase#each](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#each)

Returns a list of objects on each of which you can call val() and key().

```
team_info_snapshot = cfm.child('teams').child(team_id).get()
for team in team_info_snapshot.each():
    print(team.key()) # 0
    print(team.val()) # {"age": 1, "accelRating": 2, ...}
    print(team.val()['age']) # 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far. It's greatly appreciated. When try the recommended code I'm receiving this in the console `'list' object has no attribute 'each'`

Comment: No sir im not using pyrebase.

Comment: I'm still confused. **team_info_snapshot = cfm.child('teams').child(team_id).get()** 
             generates multiple instances of `[{'accelRating': 96, 'age': 27, 'agilityRating': 91, 'awareRating': 87, 'bCVRating'....etc}]`         So this would be a dict and age would be my key? So i dont know why I'm getting a `'list' object` error.      The code that Im trying to understand should for  example give me a count of all members with an age key of 27.

Comment: @WillJames: *"not using pyrebase"*: Thats the reason why none of my examples  worked. Updated my Answer.